# Creating an entity from String

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I do have a Spring-Data-JPA Role entity, which simply contains

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
```

where id and name are both unique.

By using the org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper, I try map the JSON body into an entity which contains my role entity:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SystemUser systemUser = mapper.readValue(body, SystemUser.class);
```

I currently end up with:

```
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class my.backend.domain.Role] from 
JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method
```

This means, I need to have a constructor in the entity: Role(String roleName). At the end, I need to get the result of:

```
select id, name from role where name=roleName
```

in the constructor Role(String role name)? Is this possible? What is the right way to solve this?

As requested here I add the information for body:

```
{"userType":"CLIENT","roles": 
["ROLEA","ROLEB"],"companyName":"asdf","address":"asdf","zipCode":"asdf",
"location":"asdf","primaryContact":"asdf","phone":"asdf","fax":"asdf",
"email":"asdf@asdf.com","customerNumber":"asdf","costCenter":"asdf"}
```

ROLEA and ROLEB are both names that are in the Role table, too.

Comment: body is a String from a REST request, I will add the information in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject repository to `Role` entity with and then use repository to fetch `Id` in factory method

```
public class Role 
{ 
   @Autowired
   @Transient
   private RoleRepo roleRepo;

   public String id;
   public String name;

   @JsonCreator
   public static Role create(String name) // factory method
   {
      return roleRepo.findRoleByName(name);;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, if you understood my question correctly, maybe I was not clear enough. I have the name, but not the id (id is Integer). I need to fetch the id from the database to instantiate the Role object.

Comment: @dexBerlin I updated the answer. `RoleRepo` is a simple `@Repository` bean that executes query with `EntityManager`. May be factory method should be marked with `@Transactional`

Comment: The issue is currently not finished, but I will confirm your answer as it puts me into the right direction. I will add information when I get more of it.